# Как произвести обработку данных столбца, содержащих значения?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Необходимо убрать в колонке name кавычки и квадратные скобки и преобразовать в список, не изменяя ячейки с отсутствующими значениями (как добавить пустое значение на этапе создания df не знаю, поэтому поставил вместо NaN - ''):

```py
d = {
    'name': [
        '', 
        ['tot', 'piter', 'carl'], 
        ['brick', 'nick'], 
        ['rick', 'reaven', 'bart', 'homer'], 
        ['rick', 'morty']
    ],
    'Date': [
        '11/05/2011', 
        '9/02/2010', 
        '1/01/2014', 
        '12/20/2020', 
        '9/30/2009'
    ],
    'Address': [
        'BY', 
        'YU', 
        'RU', 
        'BY', 
        'BY'
    ]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
```

Ответ должен выглядеть как:

| name | Date | Address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NaN | 11/05/2011 | BY |
| [tot, piter, carl] | 9/02/2010 | YU |
| [brick, nick] | 1/01/2014 | RU |
| [rick, reaven, bart, homer] | 12/20/2020 | BY |
| [rick, morty] | 9/30/2009 | BY |

Желательно, не использовать циклы.

Comment: У вас написано убрать скобки, а в примере вывода скобки есть. Так как же нужно?

Comment: у вас в желаемом примере ровно то, что появляется при создании датафрейма.

Comment: Собственно, скобки и кавычки - это просто отражение того, что это строки внутри списка. Вам нужно просто объединить строки в списке в одну строку, например: `['tot', 'piter', 'carl']` -> `'tot, piter, carl'`, так может? Тогда это просто что-то типа `.str.join(', ')` от этой колонки. А во что вы хотите `NA` превратить, или оставить их как есть? Это тоже не сложно делается и то и другое.

Comment: Я хотел изменить данные в столбце name по типу ```"['tot', 'piter', 'carl']"``` на сайте, чтобы пайтон при работе с примером определял их как строки, но не получилось (ошибку выбивает). Если есть возможность, можете исправить пример ?

Comment: d = { 'name': [ '', "['tot', 'piter', 'carl']", "['brick', 'nick']", "['rick', 'reaven', 'bart', 'homer']", "['rick', 'morty']" ], 'Date': [ '11/05/2011', '9/02/2010', '1/01/2014', '12/20/2020', '9/30/2009' ], 'Address': [ 'BY', 'YU', 'RU', 'BY', 'BY' ] } df = pd.DataFrame(data = d) - Вот так должен был выглядеть код вопроса

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поскольку не сказано, что делать с `NA`, то допустим пускай превращается в строку:

```py
df['name'] = df['name'].str.join(', ')
```

Результат:

| name | Date | Address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| <NA> | 11/05/2011 | BY |
| tot, piter, carl | 9/02/2010 | YU |
| brick, nick | 1/01/2014 | RU |
| rick, reaven, bart, homer | 12/20/2020 | BY |
| rick, morty | 9/30/2009 | BY |

Comment: Смотрите комментарии к вопросу. Я там пояснил ошибку в задании вопроса.

Comment: @lerm_on_t_off Ваш комментарий непонятен. Какой код и какую ошибку выбивает?

Comment: Я добавляю двойные кавычки в начале и в конце данных каждой ячейки столбца и мне выдаёт- код введён неверно, его нужно правильно оформлять.

Comment: @lerm_on_t_off Так покажите ваш код. Добавьте это в вопрос - ваш код и ошибку.

Comment: d = {
    'name': [
        '', 
        "['tot', 'piter', 'carl']", 
        "['brick', 'nick']", 
        "['rick', 'reaven', 'bart', 'homer']", 
        "['rick', 'morty']"
    ],
    'Date': [
        '11/05/2011', 
        '9/02/2010', 
        '1/01/2014', 
        '12/20/2020', 
        '9/30/2009'
    ],
    'Address': [
        'BY', 
        'YU', 
        'RU', 
        'BY', 
        'BY'
    ]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d) - Вот так должен был выглядеть код вопроса

Comment: Сам ваш код корректный и ошибку не выдаёт.

Comment: Сейчас попробовал отредактировать вопрос заменой, но опять ошибка(. До этого просто добавлял кавычки.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135188/discussion-between-lerm-on-t-off-and-crazyelf).

Answer (score 2):

#### Если всетаки с N/A нужно что-то делать то можно так:

```py
import pandas as pd

d = {
    'name': [
        '',
        ['tot', 'piter', 'carl'],
        ['brick', 'nick'],
        ['rick', 'reaven', 'bart', 'homer'],
        ['rick', 'morty']
    ],
    'Date': [
        '11/05/2011',
        '9/02/2010',
        '1/01/2014',
        '12/20/2020',
        '9/30/2009'
    ],
    'Address': [
        'BY',
        'YU',
        'RU',
        'BY',
        'BY'
    ]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)


def list_to_str(item: list):
    if isinstance(item, list) and item:
        return ', '.join(item)
    # Тут можно добавить дополнительную обработку

df['name'] = df['name'].apply(list_to_str)
print(df)
```

```latex
                        name        Date Address
0                       None  11/05/2011      BY
1           tot, piter, carl   9/02/2010      YU
2                brick, nick   1/01/2014      RU
3  rick, reaven, bart, homer  12/20/2020      BY
4                rick, morty   9/30/2009      BY
```

Comment: Смотрите комментарии к вопросу. Я там пояснил ошибку в задании вопроса.